# displays the selected form different tables in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have the following html coding

```
<select>
<option id="koloman" selected>Koloman</option>
<option id="display" selected>Display</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" class="button-show" value="show data" />

<table id="table-koloman">
//content of table
</table>

<table id="table-display">
//content of table
</table>
```

I want to display one of 2 existing tables, the default table that will appear first is a table "table-Koloman" because in the selection form id = "Koloman" has been selected.

If I change the id = "display" then the table id = "table-display" will appear when pressed button "show data", how jquery javascript coding for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table-display').hide();
$('.button-show').on('click', function() {
    if ($('option:selected').text() === 'Display') {
        $('#table-koloman').hide();
        $('#table-display').show();
    } else if ($('option:selected').text() === 'Koloman') {
        $('#table-koloman').show();
        $('#table-display').hide();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hRwAV/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the IDs to value attributes and then use `val` method for getting the current value of the select element.

```
<select>
    <option value="koloman" selected>Koloman</option> 
    <option value="display">Display</option> 
</select>
<input type="submit" class="button-show" value="show data">  

<table id="table-koloman"> <tbody><tr><td>first</td></tr></tbody> </table>  
<table id="table-display"> <tbody><tr><td>second</td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

```
var $table = $('table'); // cache the object 
$('.button-show').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of the event.
   var s = $('select').val(); // get the value
   $table.hide().filter('[id="table-'+s+'"]').show() // filter the tables
}).click() // trigger the click on DOM Ready
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LU3za/

Note that you can also listen to change event instead of forcing user to select an option and hit the button which is not user-friendly.

```
var $table = $('table');
$('select').change(function(e) {
      $table.hide().filter('[id="table-'+this.value+'"]').show()
}).change()
```

Comment: +1 using value attribute, perhaps a few words of explanations would give more weight to your answer.

Comment: yeah. but you added few more things, if there is a explanation that can help guys like me who are learning.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the table-koloman and show table-display after clicking on show data. If so

Give "**dropDownId**" as id to the select tag and try this

```
$('.button-show').click(function() {
    if ($('#dropDownId :selected').text() == 'Display') {
        $('#table-koloman').hide();
        $('#table-display').show();
    } else if ($('#dropDownId :selected').text() == 'Koloman') {
        $('#table-koloman').show();
        $('#table-display').hide();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table").hide();
$(".button-show").click(function(){    
    $("table").hide();
    $("#table-" + $("select").val().toLowerCase()).show();
});​
```